# How to set reference to shared inbox folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

I found this code in another search, but when I run it, I get "No Such Folder" error.

I would like to count emails in a shared inbox folder.  Can anyone advise on how to change this code to accomplish this?

```
Sub HowManyEmails()

    Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim EmailCount As Integer
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        On Error Resume Next
        Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Inbox").Folders("report's").Folders("Customer") 
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Exit Sub
        End If

    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count

    MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount, , "email count"

    Dim dateStr As String
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim msg As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set myItems = objFolder.Items
    myItems.SetColumns ("SentOn")
    ' Determine date of each message:
    For Each myItem In myItems
        dateStr = GetDate(myItem.SentOn)
        If Not dict.Exists(dateStr) Then
            dict(dateStr) = 0
        End If
        dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1
    Next myItem

    ' Output counts per day:
    msg = ""
    For Each o In dict.Keys
        msg = msg & o & ": " & dict(o) & " items" & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox msg

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetDate(dt As Date) As String
    GetDate = Year(dt) & "-" & Month(dt) & "-" & Day(dt)
End Function
```

Comment: You have `Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Inbox").Folders("report's").Folders("Customer")`.  I find it difficult to believe a shared folder is named "Personal Folders".  The first name must be the name of the shared folder.  This is actually what Outlook call a **Store** which is a file on disc.  The second name must be a folder within that store; for example "Inbox"  Each subsequent name must be folder within the previous folder.  Try getting this `Set` statement correct. .

Answer (score 0):

*You will need to update the following line of code*

```
Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Inbox").Folders("report's").Folders("Customer")
```

*Change `Personal Folders` with email address and remove the rest of the line if not needed `.Folders("report's").Folders("Customer")`*

*or simply use replace the whole line with `Set objFolder = Application.Session.PickFolder`*