# Detect incoming emails in shared accounts

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I use following code to detect when an email arrives. I have one personal Account in Outlook and three which are shared.

If an email arrives in my personal Account then the code is working and the `Debug.Print` messages appear.
If an email arrives in the other accounts, it does not work.

```vb
Public Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Debug.Print "TEST"
    Dim MailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set MailItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)
    
    Debug.Print "Neue E-Mail empfangen von: " & MailItem.SenderEmailAddress
```

Comment: NewMailEx is limited, the specific limitation, someone else could explain. Point to each non-default inbox in separate `ItemAdd`s. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49636952/how-to-set-reference-to-shared-inbox-folder